JFrog jf CLI client is unable to find the artifactory token, while it can be used using maven,
Within our project team we have some applications that are not written in a 'standard' programming language or build using a well-known build framework, hence there is no default / standard way to upload the artifacts in to artifactory.
One such application is a windows application, written in C++ and compiled and packed into an msi installer.
About 2 years ago I wrote a python tool using the artifactoryHQ module to overcome this issue.
Unfortunately that module is no longer maintained and makes use of (now) obsoleted functions.
Therefore I am looking into the JFrog CLI client 'jf'. But I seem not to be able to get this working.
It already goes wrong when I try to configure it, it states that the token I supply, which does work in maven for our Java applications, cannot be found.
Does anyone have an idea how to get this resolved?
command supplied:
**jf c add artifactory-r1 --url https://artifact-r1.xxxxx --user r1_cbs_releases_publisher --password <api-key>
**
it comes back with the message
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "message": "The user: 'token:r1_cbs_releases_publisher' not found"
    }
  ]
}

And like I said those credentials (token + api_key) works fine in maven with the same artifactory instance etc.
I came accross the command 'jf rt config ....' in one of the other questions, but that command is not valid anymore.

From your question, it is not clear if you are using a token or an API key which are two different things.
When using "jf c add" you have 2 options, use a username and password/api-key or use an access token.
If you are using a username and plain text password/api-key, the command you mentioned should work, if it is not try validating using a curl command and the flag '-u<username>' then when prompted, enter the api-key.
If you are using an access token, you should use the below command
"jf c add artifactory-r1 --url https://artifact-r1.xxxxx --access-token <token>"
The token should be only the string Artifactory generated when you created the token without the username or anything else.
